# Different date output in development and production build on Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Can anyone help me with my problem?

I fetch API from local dev, the output shown as I wanted. It is showing my current location, timezone, etc.

```
/ 20230713184522
// http://localhost:3000/api/onefootball/mylocation

{
  "continent": "Asia",
  "country": "Indonesia",
  "zipCode": null,
  "timezone": "Asia/Jakarta",
  "gmt": "(GMT+07:00) Jakarta",
  "languages": "id",
  "countryTLD": ".id",
  "countryISO2": "ID",
  "countryISO3": "IDN",
}
```

When i deploy my app to vercel and access my API route, is show different output with my development.

```
// 20230713185444
// https://xxx.xxx.dev/api/onefootball/mylocation

{
  "continent": "North America",
  "country": "United States",
  "zipCode": "95141",
  "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "gmt": "(GMT-10:00) Hawaii Time",
  "languages": "en",
  "countryTLD": ".us",
  "countryISO2": "US",
  "countryISO3": "USA",
}
```

I have tried manually to get current date, timezone using moment-timezone. Deploy it to vercel, and it also show different output.

Answer (score 1):

This difference is due to how geolocation works when using IP addresses.

When you are running your app locally, it uses your actual IP address and provides your correct geolocation details (continent, country, timezone, etc.).

However, when you deploy your app to Vercel, the server is located in a different place, hence it uses a different IP address. In your case, the server appears to be in the United States, so when it fetches the geolocation details, it gets the details for the location of the server (US) instead of your actual location.

If you just want to determine the user's timezone, the browser's JavaScript environment has access to the user's system time and can determine the timezone.

```js
const timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
console.log(timezone);
```

or

```
const now = new Date();
console.log("Time: " + now.getTime());
```

Send this information along with your request and now extract the piece of information you need from timezone / date in your api

Comment: thanks @rainversion_3, now i've fix the problem. The fetch just returning the server location all the time. I use other method to solve the problem..